# How do I copy only subdirectories but exclude other files in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix

Here is my directory structure:

```
/home/folders/test (some directories) and files
test.xml
test1.xml
test.js
images (directory)

/home/folders/test/images/( some directories ) and files
```

I have to copy the XML files and the images folder but exclude all other files.

In images, I only have to copy sub directories (with images inside) but exclude other files. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a find command to identify subdirectories would help here:

```
cp *.xml ../destination
find images -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec cp -R \{\} ../destination/images/ \;
```

Comment: Ah - so if you want just the destination folder to contain the xml files and the subdirectories then drop the last "images/" from the end of the second command.  Make sure that ../destination, and if required ../destination/images exist beforehand. "mkdir -f ../destination/images"

Answer (score 0):

I think this command will work for you...

first go to /home/folders/test and try this command.

[max@localhost file]$ find . -name "*.c" -o -name "*.jpeg" | xargs -i cp {} /home/max/Desktop/jkm/

it will copy all the ".c" and ".jpeg" files under /test (including ".c" and ".jpeg" files in the subdirectories) to a destination directory /jkm/

Comment: i think you have not understood my requirement.